# Make div go all the way down the page

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web design project for one of my classes. I cannot figure how to make the divs go down the whole page (the color)

http://jsfiddle.net/vmm1s4Lt/
http://codepen.io/bmxatvman14/pen/fihwD

Excerpt:

```
nav {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:800px;
    display:inline-block;
    /*margin-top: 40px;*/
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;    
}

#main {
    background-color:#04cfe1;
    float:right;
    width:80%;
    /*margin-right:10px;*/
}
```

Notes: I'm a pretty moderate coder, so I have tried height: 100% and that didn't do anything.

I'm trying to make the black side bar go all the way, and the blue span across the rest of the page.

Full page site: http://rubergaming.com/project/

Thanks a ton!

Comment: In addition to this you have some other problems in your markup ... for example, be aware that you can not use the same `id` on multiple elements (so there should be only one occurrence of `id="main"` in your document)

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks! I've only spent about 3hrs on this, so it was a speedy work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using height 100%, but you may have forgotten that you also need to give container elements a height of 100% in order for that to work when you are giving your `#main` div that 100% height. I also slightly modified some of your other styles, you may need to tweak as needed. http://jsfiddle.net/ngz6e5p1/.

```
/*Give containing elements, as well as our main div, a height of 100%*/
html, body, #wrapper, div#main {
    height: 100%;
}

/*This is overriding styles you already had - I changed the nav's height from 800px to 100%, and removed padding which will cause there to be an extra white space under the main blue nav if present */
nav {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton dude! I have one more question, I'm trying to get all the main part text and what not that goes over there in side a width, the only way I tried, it takes the background color with it :/

http://grab.by/AnIE <-- All that stuff

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean for the black bar to go all the way? And to span the blue div across the rest of the page try this:

```
<div id="main" style="
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20%;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
">
    //ALL THE OTHER STRUFF INSIDE THIS DIV
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing "height: 100%" do "height: 100vw;"

that will work